# How to stop this mouse focus action? It keeps reinstalling its action after I stop it

Tags: windows-10, mouse, windows-registry

I cannot remember when I activated the mouse action that whenever my mouse hovers over a window, the window becomes my main focus. Last week I googled the cause and removal and it can be removed by removing the tick in the **Control Panel > Ease of Access Centre > Change how your mouse works > Make It easier to manage Windows > Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse.**

Each time I untick it, it re-ticks itself back. Its done this thrice now. I thought maybe because I have not restarted the PC so I restarted. It still re-ticked itself. I checked here (Superuser) but most were asking about installing it in windows,  A few were comparing Windows and Linux but none were talking about taking it off and the computer reinstating it which is what my pc is doing.

So I thought maybe a regedit solution but when I Googled it, this site tells me how to make the situation also have a keyboard focus. Talk about frying pan into fire. Surely it cannot be a local policy hack afterall that is a little too granular to be imposing on others (if it is a local policy hack, then I am happy to try it as long as it works because the control panel solution is not working and this is driving me batty.

[MS-Windows focus-follows-mouse Registry hacks](https://sinewalker.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/ms-windows-focus-follows-mouse-registry-hacks/)

To reiterate - this particular Q has not been asked here prior and if it has, it has not been answered because I can't find it.

So please. registry edit hack or local policy hack.

Comment: when exactly does it reappear? right after you un-tick it, or is it re-ticked the next time you open the window?

Comment: Not sure if the issue occur when you tick a specify object such as in file explorer, or tick every thing such as IE options and control panel. We could go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\mouse to check the tick speed, make sure it is not slow.  Or we could reset PC through settings\Update & security\recovery to reset PC, it will not remove personal data.

Comment: It reappears after closing the form or after restarting the pc.

Comment: @Joy it happens whenever the mouse arrow hover over any window. That mindow becomes the focus and you can imagine installing something and the small window suddenly disappears because the mouse has to travel over a browser window which  was in the background.  Every window becomes the focus so you are constantly chasing your til as to where the right windo is. I have gobne into control panel to untick it but it just does not stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the solution was with the Graphic cards Nvidia Quadro 600 and 2000.

Whilst ticking the control panel option seems to suspend it for the duration, immediately you log out or restart, it returns. This was Nvidia had an option in its nView program that included an option to make the mouse the focus.

So unticking this finally made the mouse stop making every window the focus.
I was happy but irritated with myself. I uninstalled the program.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to click on "apply" at the bottom of the "Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center\Make the mouse easier to use" screen before leaving the screen?

It helps! :-)